# How could a starship crew get away with missing an entire day?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, time

In the TNG episode [Clues](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Clues), the crew

> deliberately wipe their memory of an alien race who want to remain undiscovered. This results in their losing one full day of memory (and presumably, at the end of the episode, *two days*).

However, when the Enterprise next interacts with Starfleet (eg docks at a space station or comes into contact with a [time beacon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_beacon)<sup>1</sup>), won't they do some kind of clock synchronisation and then realise that they've:

> missed a day (or two)?

Is there any way, in universe, that this can be explained?

<sub>This question was inspired by this: [Do ships at warp experience time dilation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14156/do-ships-at-warp-experience-time-dilation)</sub>

<sub>1 Thanks to [Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118248/how-could-a-starship-crew-get-away-with-missing-an-entire-day?noredirect=1#comment290003_118248) for this tip.</sub>

Comment: It would be a very minor mystery. I get the impression that small discrepancies in time are quite common.

Comment: @Richard: where do you get that impression from? And do you think that *one full day* (possibly more) that no one can account for would be considered a *"small discrepancy"*?

Comment: When you're dealing with mini-wormholes, spacial rifts and traveling about at speeds above lightspeed, I'm pretty confident that missing time is a regular feature of starfleet life.

Comment: @Richard: I think that if they can track mass to the [molecular level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_(Star_Trek)) they should also be able to track time to the nanosecond, despite anomalies. *If* they experience time dilation at warp (the linked question), then they should be able to account for travelling at speeds above light speed. And they don't take the Enterprise through spacial rifts that often!

Comment: Time-slippage is evidently such a common problem that they have [time beacons](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Time-base_beacon) specifically to deal with the problem

Comment: @Richard - good find! But then that only reinforces my question: they hit the first time beacon which says they are missing one (or two) days - and they have no explanation for it.

Comment: Precisely. A minor mystery and one that probably doesn't merit a 50 day backtrack

Comment: Although the *crew* lost a day, the ship's chronometers would still be on track. What are technology-centered people like the Federation going to trust - the ship's clocks or their own subjective feeling that everything seems a little off?

Comment: @JoeL.: the question is not comparing subjective feeling with the ship's clocks. It is about comparing the ship's clocks with other Federation clocks.

Comment: After checking both Memory Alpha and the IMDB entry for the episode, it looks like this is a [plot hole.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotHole) The writers could have thrown in a line about the supposed wormhole kicking them a day or two off in time, but I guess they didn't think of it.

Comment: @JoeL. - I disagree that it's a plot-hole. There's a perfectly rational in-universe explanation.

Comment: @Richard: "Time-slippage is evidently such a common problem that they have time beacons specifically to deal with the problem" - time-slippage is not a common problem in our world, and yet [technical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock) for synchronizing clocks are commonplace nowadays. Accordingly, I do not see a reason to assume the existence of time beacons indicates that time-slippage is a common problem.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - This is a fictional universe in which people are openly advised not to travel too close to the speed of light in case they suffer relativity effects and who encounter time distortions with such alarming regularity that they have an entire department devoted to undoing all the paradoxes caused. Times that by the entire fleet and it's hardly surprising that time beacons are required.

Comment: I find it hilarious that people think time is real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wormholes and other spacial rifts are well known in the Star Trek universe to have both spacial *and temporal* components. Given that Picard thinks that they've traveled through a highly unstable wormhole, the discrepancy between the ship's chronometer and Federation chronometers could easily be explained as one of the effects of the wormhole itself; only 30 seconds passed *subjectively* (e.g. on board the ship), but a whole day passed *objectively* (e.g. in the rest of the universe):

> **PICARD:** *The ship just went through a wormhole. The entire crew was unconscious for approximately thirty seconds.*

---

Note that a *lack* of [temporal variance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Temporal_variance) is one of the key things that Chakotay scans for when the crew of the Voyager encounters a wormhole. There's obviously no point using one if the other end comes out next to Earth **but in the year 2,000,000 B.C.**

> **CHAKOTAY:** *He's right. No subspatial contortions, no temporal variance.* - <sub><sup>[Voy: Bliss](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/515.htm)</sup></sub>

---

Since the ability to travel *forwards* in time would be of little use or interest to the Federation, there's no point in further investigating a phenomenon that's inherently dangerous but has no intrinsic value.

Comment: But they didn't pass through a wormhole in that episode.

Comment: I meant "Clues" from my question.

Comment: @Wikis - No, but they *think* they went through a wormhole. When they discover the clocks are off, they'll probably put it down to "temporal variance". The exit of the wormhole is 24 hours later than the entrance.

Comment: Good point. I was going to suggest you add that to the answer but you have already done so...

Comment: Put another way: They might consider themselves lucky that their clocks are only 1 or 2 days off after the encounter with a wormhole. The crew of the USS Bozeman probably wishes their subspace anomaly encounter was so good. Same for the crew of the USS Voyager when they discovered a micro-wormhole to the Alpha Quadrant -- (20 yrs in the past).

Answer (score -1):

In ST:Enterprise's second season episode "A night in sickbay", we hear the Kreetassans say:

> KREETASSAN [on viewscreen]: Why haven't you adjusted your time to our capital city?

Indicating that it is common to shift the chronometer to the particular part of space you're visiting. Perhaps skipping a day while doing so doesn't raise eyebrows.

[Chakoteya.NET - a night in sickbay](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/30.htm)

Comment: That was more about adjusting the day/night cycle, not changing the actual clock

Comment: I personally haven't flown intergalactic starships, but on inter-continental flights, I adjust to their day/night cycle by setting my clock.

Comment: You might reset your watch to local time but I think you'd notice if your flight took 34 hours instead of 10