# How to convert Stardate to Gregorian calendar date?

Tags: star-trek, stardate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do stardates work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14130/how-do-stardates-work)

The accepted answer to this question: [How do stardates work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14130/how-do-stardates-work) has some points, but still I have difficulties in conversion.

For example, I have found `Stardate 64333.4` in *Star Trek: Countdown* comic which was launched as prequel of 2009 Star Trek movie. This stardate is stated by comic writer to us... not by a starship captain in captain's log. So, I don't think, it has an affect with vessel's warp.

Plus, stardate is universal standard among many races. So, there must be a local conversion standards of individual races. I'm just asking for that of humans.

Comment: The answer on the other question is about as definitive as you can get, I think.  In TNG/DS9/VOY-style Stardates, `64333.4` about 1/3rd through 2387, around 9:30 AM.

Comment: In the 2009 movie's version of Stardates, `64333.4` is the 4th day of the year 64333.

Comment: @Izakta Are you saying 2387 because Romulus was destroyed in same year? Can you state exact mathematical formula which is applicable on atleast TNG/DS9/VOY?

Comment: @Izakta And, how do you get 9:30AM?

Comment: 'Tis an answer now ;)

Answer (score -1):

From the linked question:

> **The Original Series, the Star Trek Guide:**
>
> > Pick any combination of four numbers plus a percentage point, use it
> >     as your story's stardate. For example, 1313.5 is twelve o'clock noon
> >     of one day and 1314.5 would be noon of the next day.
>
> **From the Star Trek: The Next Generation Writer's/Director's Guide:**
>
> > A stardate is a five-digit number followed by a decimal point and one
> >     more digit. Example: "41254.7." The first two digits of the stardate
> >     are always "41." The 4 stands for 24th century, the 1 indicates first
> >     season. The additional three leading digits will progress unevenly
> >     during the course of the season from 000 to 999. The digit following
> >     the decimal point is generally regarded as a day counter.

And from the [Stardate](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stardate#The_Next_Generation_era) page on Memory Alpha that the other answer references, evidence that TNG/DS9/VOY-era used decimal digits the same as TOS-era:

> In addition to the overall rate of approximately 1,000 units per year,
>   many episodes confirm the 24-hour stardate unit which was first
>   mentioned in the TOS bible, with midnight at .0 and noon at .5.

So, how did I come up with that particular date?

In-universe, the first season of TNG occured in 2364.  Stardate 64333.4 is (64-41=23) 23 years after Stardate 41xxx, the first season of TNG.  So 64xxx corresponds to the year 2387 (2364+23).

It is 1/3rd through the year because 333 is about 1/3rd of 1000, the length of a year.

9:30 AM comes from the .4, which means the day is 40% completed.  According to Google, that's [9.6 hours](https://www.google.com/search?q=40%25%20of%20one%20day) - 9:36 AM.

Comment: Coincidentally, we are currently only about 9-10 days short of being 1/3rd through the year ;)

Comment: You've copied & pasted like dumb: `The first two digits of the stardate are always "41." The 4 stands for 24th century` ~> Why don't 6 stands for 26th century...

Comment: From answer of that question, `.4` should tell about day of year. How did you calculate time using `.4`?

Comment: @SachinShekhar `The 4 stands for 24th century, the 1 indicates first season.`, and 42 is the second season (1 year later), 43 is the 3rd season, and so on.  The linked question/answer goes on with examples that the "4" indicating "24th century" was abandoned, and that those digits simply indicate the year/tv season.

Comment: @SachinShekhar As for the `.4`, read the rest of this answer.  It wasn't used as a day counter onscreen.

Comment: @SachinShekhar An additional answer I made on the same topic that basically just shows that the writers weren't consistent:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14461/2242